# ‘file://’ has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn’t pass access control check:

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using ionic3 for my application development. I am getting the below error for the first time installation of my Android application. Then, after re-launching, the app is working correctly.

I'm seeing this issue only on a new/fresh install of the app. Restarting the app resolves the issue, which is strange.

I have been seeing this issue after I set targetSdkVersion 28 i.e, building app for Android 9 pie.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at ‘the url’ from origin ‘file://’ has been blocked by CORS policy: No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested resource’.

My App Configuration:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC2Ix.jpg)

Comment: This is more of system configuration related issue. Chrome WebView version of 76.0.xxx.xx It will be fixed in later versions of Chrome. For complete information [click here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=991107&q=cordova&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified).

Comment: It looks like you gave more than enough information for people to understand and solve the issue, but if you want to be extra-super-tidy, you left out the error that appears after setting cleartextTrafficPermitted="True". It's definitely not necessary, though!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of a new WebView update: 76.0.3809.89

There's a [known bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=991107) from Android.

The fix (version 76.0.3809.111) [has started to be rolled out](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2019/08/chrome-for-android-update.html).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I took the liberty of tweaking the URLs in your response to make them neater. [text](url), so that you know in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your path by this way

```
this.file = (<any>window).Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(fileSrc)
```